# Pandas: How to check the nth character in a column is in a specified list and replace it?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The dataframe looks like this:

```
ID Desc
1  Hello
2  How
3  Have
4  You
5  Been
```

And I want to check if the third character of Desc is in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], not case-sensitive, and replace it to 'Replaced'.

What I've tried was:

```
df.loc[df['Desc'].str[2] in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] == True), 'Desc'] = 'Replaced'.
```

But it spits out an error that

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas-series-isin):

```
df['Desc'].str[2].str.lower().isin([*'abcde'])
```

Yeilds

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: Desc, dtype: bool
```

And, now:

```
df.loc[df['Desc'].str[2].str.lower().isin([*'abcde']), 'Desc'] = 'Replaced'
df
```

Output:

```
   ID      Desc
0   1     Hello
1   2       How
2   3      Have
3   4       You
4   5  Replaced
```